# Getting the error code from an IOException

Tags: c#, exception, accessor

Getting the (hex) error code from an IOException, or regular Exception!

Is this possible? i know it HAS a error code, (HResult) but the get accessor is private.

I would do some sort of ComException thing, but im not sure about the pros/cons of doing this, and if its even possible/the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-clr/1561/How-To-Get-HResult-From-IOException) it is suggested to call Marshall.GetHRForException.

Comment: that seems to work! :) I had actually just found that and returned to post my own answer but you beat me :P

Answer (score 0):

Derive a specified class from Exception or IOException and expose the HRESULT value through an internal property.

```
class MyException:Exception
{
   internal GetHRResult()
   {
       return base.get_HResult();
   } 
   .....
}
```

Comment: that would be good, except for i tried that and for some reason, (IOexceptionNameHere as MyException) returns null.

Comment: looks like i cant cast the exception to a custom one.